# How can I get LotusScript to release my VB.NET DLL

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, lotus-notes, lotusscript

In Visual Studio 2015, I've written a bespoke DLL in VB.NET to use via COM in a Lotusscript agent, and it works very nicely. However, until I close Notes, I am unable to rebuild the DLL, as the file is still is use.

If I try to delete the DLL manually to allow the rebuild, I get the error message "*The action can't be completed because the file is open in IBM Notes/Domino*".

If I close Notes, I can delete it without any problem.  While this is just about bearable during development, the DLL is destined for the server, so this is obviously a problem, as I don't want to have to restart the server to change my DLL if necessary.

For reference, I'm installing the DLL for COM use using regasm /codebase, and accessing the class using

```
Set object = CreateObject("Name.Class")
```

I've tried adding `Delete object` in the Terminate event of the agent but that doesn't work.

Comment: Unloading the DLL can only happen when the primary AppDomain is unloaded.  That can only happen when you use the ICLRMetaHost interface to custom-host the CLR.  That's all technically possible, the odds that you can make that work from inside Notes ought to be rather small.

Comment: When running on the Domino server, you woudn't have restart the server, but you would have to restart the AMGR task, or the HTTP task if it's a web agent.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, oh that's a thought. It's not a web agent, but restarting Amgr is perfectly feasible when required.